# PopUp screen not opening In webview Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, webview, android-jetpack-compose, popup, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The problem with displaying JavaScript alerts in WebView on Android using Material Design 3
I am working on an Android application that uses WebView to display web content. Everything works well on a smartphone or tablet. But the model(popup) is not displayed in the monoblock(an android device that is mainly used by cashiers and something like that)

This is my code

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                settings.apply {
                    javaScriptEnabled = true
                    domStorageEnabled = true
                    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                    setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                }
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                        view: WebView?,
                        request: WebResourceRequest?
                    ): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                    override fun onJsAlert(
                        view: WebView?,
                        url: String?,
                        message: String?,
                        result: JsResult?
                    ): Boolean {
                        result?.confirm()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                loadUrl(PAGE_URL)
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl(PAGE_URL)
        }
    )
}
```